# how to upload django app on VPS with cent os

Tags: python, django, vps

I am new in Django and I finished my first Django app with sqlite recently.
Now I have a VPS with linux cent os.
Please give me a source for full structure of how to Upload my app to my VPS.(I have no experience in server, so it can be great give me some info for configuration of server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broad question short answer.

> Setup git in your project and create the bare repo in your VPS and using that as remote url and push your local changes and and make clone for prod and dev.

#### VPS:

```
git init --bare your-project

your remote url is user@<ip>:/home/user/your-project
```

#### local:

```
git remote add origin user@<ip>:/home/user/your-project

push using git push origin master
```

Comment: I am using pycharm in local, I done "git init --bare myprojectname"

Comment: Hm... okay try https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/using-git-integration.html

Comment: what shod i do after git init --bare your-project??

Comment: you dont have to do anything.... in your local machine try `git clone user@<ip>:/home/user/your-project`

Comment: ok, so after git init --bare your-project on Vps, how to upload my django local app on Vps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110346/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-mohammad-gh).